# Adjust table columns proportionally

Tags: tables

I have created a table with multi-columns and wanted to make sure that it was as wide as the text and above all that the columns were equally divided in space.
I tried \tabularx but I don't understand how to set it.

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lccc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & col 1     & col 2     & col 3     \\ \hline
                     & \multicolumn{3}{c}{merged column} \\ \hline
row1                 & value     & value     & value     \\
row2                 & value     & value     & value     \\
row3                 & value     & value     & value    
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:non-parametric}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Edited, sorry for the previous wall of code. It's my first post here.

Comment: Any news? You receive two answers, does no one deserve to be upvoted (by clicking in up-triangle at top left side of answers) or even the one, which on the best way fulfill your expectation to be accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Using `tabularx` at least one column had to be of `X` or from it derived type. In your case is sensible to derive new column type:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

and than use it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X CCC}
        & col 1     & col 2     & col 3     \\ \hline
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{merged column} \\ \hline
row1    & value     & value     & value     \\
row2    & value     & value     & value     \\
row3    & value     & value     & value     \\  \hline
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{merged column} \\ \hline
row1    & value     & value     & value     \\
row2    & value     & value     & value     \\
row3    & value     & value     & value     \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:non-parametric}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produce

[image]

what is to my opinion not very nice looking table (if reali text in cells are not wider as dummy content in your code fragment).

You may be interested to use `tabularray` package instead `tabularx` which in companion of `booktabs` package loaded as `tabularray` library gives:

[image]

Using it, a table code is wee bit shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[l] *{3}{X[c]}}}
        & col 1     & col 2     & col 3     \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-4}
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c}{merged column} 
                    &           &           \\ 
    \midrule
row1    & value     & value     & value     \\
row2    & value     & value     & value     \\
row3    & value     & value     & value     \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c}{merged column}
                    &           &           \\
    \midrule
row1    & value     & value     & value     \\
row2    & value     & value     & value     \\
row3    & value     & value     & value     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:non-parametric}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback too!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I have understood your problem clearly. If you want a table with all the columns having the same width, you may use [fixed-width columns](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Text_wrapping_in_tables).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

% left aligned fixed-width column
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

% centered fixed-width column
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{L{0.2\textwidth} *{3}{C{0.2\textwidth}}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & col 1     & col 2     & col 3     \\ \hline
                     & \multicolumn{3}{c}{merged column} \\ \hline
row1                 & value     & value     & value     \\
row2                 & value     & value     & value     \\
row3                 & value     & value     & value    
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:non-parametric}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, all the columns have same width. For better understanding, see the table with vertical rules

[image: vrules]

Addendum:

A somewhat better-looking (to me) version of your table with the use of the horizontal rules from the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{L{0.2\textwidth} *{3}{C{0.2\textwidth}}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & col 1     & col 2     & col 3     \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
                     & \multicolumn{3}{c}{merged column} \\ \midrule
row1                 & value     & value     & value     \\
row2                 & value     & value     & value     \\
row3                 & value     & value     & value  
\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:non-parametric}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Edit according to the OP's comment: `X` type column of the `tabularx` package should be used. The command `\centering\arraybacklash` is used for horizontal centering.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & col 1     & col 2     & col 3     \\ \hline
                     & \multicolumn{3}{c}{merged column} \\ \hline
row1                 & value     & value     & value     \\
row2                 & value     & value     & value     \\
row3                 & value     & value     & value    
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:non-parametric}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. The problem is that after I set the table to be as wide as the text, the columns do not adjust accordingly and they all stay on the left. I edit my initial question so you can see my output.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I also much prefer your version. I don't understand how the packages you mentioned work, but I'll copy the sample you posted and try to build the table I need.

Comment: @D.Milani Added another table. Did you want something like this?

Comment: @D.Milani In the 2nd table, I have used two packages. One is `booktabs` which introduces the `\toprule, \midrule, \cmidrule`, and `\bottomrule` commands for better horizontal rules. The other package is the `array` package which defines `m` type column. You may read sections 2.2, 2.8, 7.2, and 12 of [this wikibook chapter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for